# ASP.NET how to render a custom template and pass it into a main template

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, templates

I can make the same in `Django` using `render_to(...)` but ASP.NET.

I need to provide the different form in a single asp.net page, so I want to render custom form templates and pass it into a main page.

How to make this stuff?

I try this code

`<%: Html.RenderPartial(ViewData["pd"].ToString(), ViewData)%>`

and I get

`'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartial' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)' has some invalid arguments`

Sultan

Comment: renderpartial doesn't do what you want???

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC or not?

Comment: I'm relatively new to asp.net development, mostly I work `Django` and now I want to take a closer look at ASP.NET MVC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Django, but from your description it looks like you are talking about partial views. So you could define a partial (`~/Views/Home/Foo.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<div>some contents</div>
```

and then in your main view include it:

```
<%= Html.Partial("Foo") %>
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have shown your code it seems that you are using the `RenderPartial` method. This method doesn't return anything. It writes directly to the output. You are using it incorrectly. It should be used like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial(ViewData["pd"].ToString()); %>
```

or you could also use the Partial helper:

```
<%= Html.Partial(ViewData["pd"].ToString()) %>
```

Now as far as passing info to this partial is concerned I would very very very strongly recommend you getting rid of any ViewData and use strongly typed views and view models. So for example you would have a strongly typed main view to this model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherViewModel Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and then you will be able to do this:

```
<%= Html.Partial(Model.Foo, Model.Bar) %>
```

and then have your partial strongly typed to `SomeOtherViewModel`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SomeOtherViewModel>" %>
<div><%: Model.SomePropertyOfBar %></div>
```

Or even better, use the [templated helpers Html.DisplayFor and Html.EditorFor](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/08/13/htmldisplayforinaspnetmvc2.aspx). They are the best way to include partials into an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: But how to make the same `ViewData` visible inside of my partial?

Comment: @sultan, I would recommend you using strongly typed models and views and not relying on any ViewData. But if you really need to use it you could pass it as second argument to the Partial helper.

Comment: @sultan, see my update about view models and display templates.

Comment: I used `ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView` instead of `ViewEngines.Engines.FindView` and it worked. Thanks @Darin Dimitrov

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebForms, you can use MasterPage.